# Having issues with bingmap in android 4.4 (kitkat)

Tags: android

i m using bingmap in my app and its working fine till jellybean version.
When i set the target to 4.4, the bing map is just loading the continents alone and not pointing the current location.

On Debugging, found out that the  map loaded event handler callback is not getting called.

Below is the code snippet for maploadedlistener.

```
       //Add a map loaded event handler
     bingMapsView.setMapLoadedListener(new MapLoadedListener() {
        public void onAvailableChecked() {
            mIsMapReady = true;
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    _gpsLayer = new EntityLayer(Constants.DataLayers.GPS);
                    bingMapsView.getLayerManager().addLayer(_gpsLayer);
                    updateGPSPin();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Has anyone faced the same issue with android 4.4?
ALso please suggest some remedy.

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution now is hide the map first and show after finish loading and I also lock the touch function while zooming.